# keyboard open layout override in android

Tags: java, android

this is my xml file layout when keyboard is open my bottom view also scroll

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_education_school"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                android:textColor="#2e2e2e"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:hint="School Name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_education_degree"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#2e2e2e"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:hint="Degree" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_education_field_of_study"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#2e2e2e"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:hint="Field Of Study" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_education_start_date"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Start Date"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:textColor="#2e2e2e"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_education_end_date"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="End Date"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:textColor="#2e2e2e"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_education_activities"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#2e2e2e"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:hint="Activities" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_education_save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:text="Save"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_delete_education"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="#222222"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:text="Delete Education" />
```

when i open the keyboard my textview (tv_delete_education) is override on text 
[image]

i want to fix my textview in bottom navigation no required to scroll. i also add in menifest file `adjustPan ,adjustResize` but still not work for me if any kind of help let me know thanks in advance

Comment: Use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" under activity in. manifest

Comment: @ADM i try it but still get same issues

Comment: Are you sure this xml is you are using? ScrollView And TextView is both at parent level in xml?

Comment: @JatinDevani try my answer and let me know if any query.

Comment: @JatinDevani add this line in manifest in activity tag 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in android manifest android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" 
for activity.It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is basic format for your design and its working.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.whiz_010.myapplication.ui.home.MainActivity">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Title"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Company"
                   />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Location"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Start Date"
                        />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="End Date"
                        />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Delete Experience"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.home.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```